# esconder o hacer visibles div

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando hacer que sea visible un div o no, cuando el tamaño de la pantalla sea menor a 900px pero no me ha funcionado. sigue apareciendo las dos imagenes que tengo en el div. Les agradeceria en gran manera su ayuda.

```css
<style type="text/css">

        /*Si la pantalla es menor a 900px*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 980px){
        #sipequ{
            display: none !important;
        }
        #responsE{
            display: none;
            }
    }
    /*Si la pantalla es mayor a 981px*/
    @media screen and (min-width: 981px){
        #sigran{
            display: none !important;
        }
        #responsD{
            display:none;
            }
    }

</style>
```

```html
<div id="sigran" data-src="images/slider/oro-orodo.png">
  <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom cap1">10 años haciendo realidad sus proyectos de distribución.</div>
</div>
<div id="sipequ" data-src="images/slider/oro-orodo_2.png">
  <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom cap1">10 años haciendo realidad sus proyectos de distribución.</div>
</div>
```

```
        display: none !important;
    }
}

/*Si la pantalla es mayor a 981px*/
@media screen and (min-width: 981px){
    #sigran{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quita las etiquetas `<style>`. Esas etiquetas se ponen para añadir estilos en el HTML, en el CSS no es una sintaxis correcta

Comment: Hola David, podrías montar el codigo en un servicio como JSbin, JSFiddle o CodePen?, yo he hecho la prueba y solo veo un div a la vez...

Answer (score -2):

Prueba adaptando este codigo que encontre a lo que tu necesitas. acuerdate de asignarle las clase `.search_and_share`

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .search_and_share {
      display:none;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
   .search_and_share{
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Matias, gracias por tu respuesta.     implemente elcodigo que me diste pero no funciono :                  `<div class="search_and_share" data-src="images/slider/oro-orodo.png">
    <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom cap1">10 años .</div>
 </div>
                                                                   <div class="search_and_share" data-src="images/slider/oro-orodo_2.png">
 <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom cap1">10 años.</div>
</div>`